# Linq - join tables and populate a single object

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a project where I deal with "products".
There products have many different attributes, all stored in the product table. Due to performance issues, there is a table called "reputation" that stores the information about the reputation of a product.

The "Product" class has many properties for the different attributes and a property for the reputation information.

I would like to use linq to query the database using a join.

The problem is: how do I say that "everything coming from the product table should populate the respective property in the product class and the reputation info should populate the "reputation" property"?

I have this code, I am feeling I am near, but I didn't managed it yet...

```
var product = (from product in product.Table
                     join reputation in reputation.Table 
on product.ProductId equals reputation.ProductId
                     select new Product { Reputation = reputation
                     }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Where do I set the other attributes? Something like "Product = Product.*"

Thanks!

Edit: The product class contains the reputation info, it was separated in the db for performance issue

Comment: what is the problem of query?

Comment: Can you post your model?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you question...

Comment: The previous comments was meant for habib. @mark, as soon as I have access to it, I will

Comment: i think  "select product" is your answer.because product and  Reputation  has same product.ProductId .

Comment: you cannot use var product = (from product in product.Table ....   "product" used in the "from product ..." . syntax error

Comment: @MarkOreta My model (Product) is extremely large, is it enough if I tell you that it contains all the fields in the Product Table + all the fields in the reputation table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I could research, it is not possible, but an alternate solution is to batch the selects, searching first for products and then for reputation, merging them manually after, as it can be seen here:

http://tonesdotnetblog.wordpress.com/2008/07/23/linq-to-sql-batches-and-multiple-results-without-stored-procedures-by-tony-wright/

Answer (score 0):

- You cannot select new Product since you have extra field which is
  reputation and it's not in Product class (I assume).
- Note,    SingleOrDefault() will throw exception if you have more that
  one    result so I do not see any point in this case using that.
- Instead of    select new Product you can select new { all fileds you 
  need to    populate = corresponding values} You need explicitly write
  all what    you need, you cannot use something like product.*

Comment: The product class contains the reputation info, it was separated in the db for performance issue

Comment: So, just go with the 3rd proposal to list all properties in select new Product { ... }

Comment: The class has over 25 properties, it is huge :(. What do you think about habib's answer in the comments? Select product should work because they share the same productid?

Comment: Don't you miss reputation in that case? Of course you may have new class which has Product field and class related to reputation and then do select new SuperProduct { ProductDesc = product, ReputationDesc = reputation }

Comment: Habib means that they will be merged because they have the same productId (at least this is what I understood). 
I would go with this approach before asking the question, but I am adapting an existing system and "product" is being used all over the place. Maybe I will just create a second query (second DB hit) to get the reputation info and populate it manually :(